# how to install node-pre-gyp binaries from local file

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, node-pre-gyp

I have some firewall restrictions and can't download some prebuild binaries for alpine, so i thinked that i can download locally the binary file and set the path somewhere. I did it with prebuild-install libraries like keytar, puting in .npmrc file

```
keytar_local_prebuilds=/tmp
```

There's a way to do the same with node-pre-gyp binaries? for example, bcrypt@5.0.1 (file bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz)

I have the files in a blob storage, so i can download them in the dockerfile.

Comment: I have same question and found this PR: https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/pull/459 maybe this can help?